# Composer not working with laravel after Windows update 1903

Tags: php, windows, laravel, composer-php

Yesterday I updated my windows from version 1803 to 1903. Today I tried to continue work on my laravel application and tried to run `PHP artisan serve` for development.

What I got was an error message:

> PHP Warning:  require(C:\Users\MY_USERNAME\MY_PROJECT/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in artisan on line 18
>
> Warning: require(C:\Users\MY_USERNAME\MY_PROJECT/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in artisan on line 18
>   PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'C:\Users\MY_USERNAME\MY_PROJECT/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in artisan on line 18
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\Users\MY_USERNAME\MY_PROJECT/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in artisan on line 18

But those files exist. I did not change anything after updating to windows 1903.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you haven't installed Composer dependencies so

Cd To your project and run `composer install` in your terminal

Comment: Did you delete my comment? This answer doesn't fix anything. I already did that and it just says that composer.json doesn't exist. But it does exist in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem because of the Windows update and I couldn't do `composer install` in my original project because it didnt find the composer.json, so... I pushed it on Github, downloaded and then made composer install on the new project and it works. Maybe it's not the best solution... but worked for me